# Django CORS Method not allowed

Tags: django, cors, django-rest-framework, django-cors-headers

I use django-cors-headers and django-rest-framework.

My frontender get error:

[image]

Preflight response:

[image]

I tested with curl, all looks fine:

[image]

Can't understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

The CORS issue is explained [in the documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/ajax-csrf-cors/#cors).
In short, you're performing a call across domains which CORS protection doesn't allow.